# Scrapy check for duplicates pipeline

Tags: python, scrapy, amazon-dynamodb

I'm passing a timestamp to **DynamoDB** through a plugin I downloaded. The spider is on cron for every two minutes. Before, it used to take a timestamp from a website XPath, so it was unique; but at the moment every new run generates a new timestamp, so it creates a new entry every single run. Can you please direct me to a pipeline solution to check if the same `url` already exists, so the spider skips it at all?

My spider:

```
def parse(self, response):

    for item in response.xpath("//li[contains(@class, 'river-block')]"):
        url = item.xpath(".//h2/a/@href").extract()[0]
        stamp = Timestamp().timestamp
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.get_details, meta={'stamp': stamp})

def get_details(self, response):
        article = ArticleItem()
        article['title'] = response.xpath("//header/h1/text()").extract_first()
        article['url'] = format(shortener.short(response.url))
        article['stamp'] = response.meta['stamp']
        yield article
```

My pipeline:

```
class DynamoDBStorePipeline(object):

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb',region_name="us-west-2")

    table = dynamodb.Table('x')

    table.put_item(
    Item={
    'url': str(item['url']),
    'title': item['title'].encode('utf-8'),
    'stamp': item['stamp'],
    }
    )
    return item
```

Answer (score 0):

By default Scrapy doesn't perform an identical request multiple times.

For more information you can read [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request) about **dont_filter** who is false by default to ignore the duplicates filter.

anyway another solution, you can create an array, and check if your title exists in your array. i think that is better to check duplication here than in pipeline, because if are in duplication case, you won't do another thing that you don't need

```
url  = response.xpath("//header/h1/text()").extract_first()
if( url not in yourArray) :
    article = ArticleItem()
    article['title'] = response.xpath("//header/h1/text()").extract_first()
    article['url'] = url
    article['stamp'] = response.meta['stamp']
    yourArray.append(url)
    yield article
```

Comment: this will check against items in my DynamoDB?

Comment: the code that i wrote give you the items with unique url, that means you won't have 2 items with the same url.

Comment: urls are unique. timestamps are not because they get generated everytime cron runs. I tried `attribute_not_exists` but that didn't help me. I think i need `exists()` but I don't know how to implement it. Pretty new to Python

Comment: i retried `attribute_not_exists` claiming both has and sort keys and it seems to be working so far

Answer (score 0):

After digging through stackoverflow questions and Boto3 documentation I was able to come up with solution:

```
class DynamoDBStorePipeline(object):

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb',region_name="us-west-2")

    table = dynamodb.Table('x')

    table.put_item(
    Item={
    'link': str(item['link']),
    'title': item['title'].encode('utf-8'),
    'stamp': item['stamp'],
    },
    ConditionExpression = 'attribute_not_exists(link) AND attribute_not_exists(title)',
    )
    return item
```